# Identifying rows and columns of a matrix that satisfy a specific feature

Tags: matrix, pattern-matching, code-request

Originally, I have a matrix of dimension (1040, 1040). This a very large matrix to visually inspect some features. I mimic the matrix of concern as:

```
mat={
     {1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 7, 0, 9, 10, 11, 0, 13, 14, 15, 0},
     {17, 18, 19, 0, 21, 22, 23, 0, 25, 26, 27, 0, 29, 30, 31, 0},
     {33, 34, 35, 0, 37,38, 39, 0, 41, 42, 43, 0, 45, 46, 47, 0}, 
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {65, 66, 67, 0, 69, 70, 71, 0, 73, 74, 75, 0, 77, 78, 79, 0}, 
     {81, 82, 83, 0, 85, 86, 87, 0, 89, 90, 91, 0, 93, 94, 95, 0}, 
     {97,98,99,0,101,102, 103, 0, 105, 106, 107, 0,109, 110, 111, 0}, 
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {129,130,131,0,133,134,135,0,137,138,139,0,141,142,143, 0},
     {145,146,147,0,149,150,151,0,153,154,155,0,157, 158, 159, 0},
     {161,162,163,0,165,166,167,0,169,170, 171, 0, 173, 174, 175, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {193, 194, 195, 0,197,198, 199, 0,201,202,203,0,205,206,207, 0}, 
     {209,210,211,0,213, 214, 215, 0, 217, 218,219,0,221,222,223, 0},
     {225, 226, 227, 0, 229, 230, 231,0,233,234,235,0,237,238,239,0}, 
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    }
```

As seen, matrix `mat` has some rows and columns with all zero entries.

1. I like to identify those rows and columns with all zero entries. For example, using `mat`, I like to have a list of row indices showing the row index numbers associated with zero-entry rows: {4, 8, 12, 16}. Likewise, for the column index, {4, 8, 12, 16}.
2. Then, after constructing the row/column index lists, I like to remove those zero rows/columns from the original matrix `mat`.

Using `Drop[mat,{.,.},{.,.}]`, I can accomplish the above goal for the given matrix `mat` as zero rows and columns are placed systematically. But my problem is that I cannot see the actual `mat` visually and the zero rows/columns are unsystematically placed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The following will do what you want: `Transpose[Transpose[mat] /. {0 ..} -> Nothing[]] /. {0 ..} -> 
  Nothing[]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nonzerorows = Flatten @ Position[mat, Except @ {0 ..}, 1, Heads -> False]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15}
> ```

```
nonzerocols = Flatten @ Position[Transpose @ mat, Except @ {0 ..}, 1, Heads -> False]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15}
> ```

```
mat1 = mat[[nonzerorows, nonzerocols]];

mat1 // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
{zerorows, zerocols} = MapThread[Complement[Range @ # @ Dimensions[mat], #2] &, 
  {{First, Last}, {nonzerorows, nonzerocols}}]
```

> ```
>  {{4, 8, 12, 16}, {4, 8, 12, 16}}
> ```

```
mat2 = DeleteCases[{}] @ ReplacePart[mat, 
   {Alternatives @@ zerorows, _} | {_, Alternatives @@ zerocols} -> Nothing];

mat2 == mat1
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

You can get the final matrix directly using

```
mat3 = Nest[DeleteCases[{0 ..}] @* Transpose, mat, 2]

mat3 == mat1
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is:

```
z = Position[mat, {0 ..}];
c = Position[Transpose@mat, {0 ..}];

Delete[Transpose@Delete[mat // Transpose, c], z]
```

An alternative is:

```
Select[Transpose[Select[mat, Not[And @@ PossibleZeroQ[#]] &]], 
  Not[And @@ PossibleZeroQ[#]] &] // Transpose
```

Answer (score 3):

A row of all zeros also sums to zero... so you can apply Total to sum the elements of each row and then select the positions that are zero:

```
Position[Total[mat], _?((# == 0) &)]

{{4}, {8}, {12}, {16}}
```

If you just want the row numbers, you can Flatten. For columns, do the same thing to the transpose of mat. If your matrix has both positive and negative entries, apply Abs to mat.

Comment: In the example matrix I gave above, it happens to be that all the entries are greater or equal to zero. However, my original matrix has both positive and negative entries, which may create zero Total, while the individual entries are not zero.

Comment: Then use Abs when you sum...

Comment: That is right. Thank you very much. I have now many alternative formulations to consider.